# Explicit line ranges when parsing YAML in Python

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have the following YAML file contents (a single block for example):

```yaml
.deploy_container:
  tags:
    - gcp
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  services:
    - docker:find
  variables:
    PORT: "$APP_PORT"
  script:
    - cp $GCP_SERVICE_KEY gcloud-service-key.json # Google Cloud
```

I have a wrapper for the default `SafeLoader`:

```py
class SafeLineLoader(SafeLoader):
    def construct_mapping(self, node: MappingNode, deep: bool = False) -> dict[Hashable, Any]:
        mapping = super().construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)

        mapping['__startline__'] = node.start_mark.line + 1
        mapping['__endline__'] = node.end_mark.line + 1
        return mapping
```

Given the file contents and loader, the parsed object I get is:

```json
{
  ".deploy_container": {
    "tags": [
      "gcp"
    ],
    "image": "google/cloud-sdk",
    "services": [
      "docker:find"
    ],
    "variables": {
      "PORT": "$APP_PORT",
      "__startline__": 137,
      "__endline__": 138
    },
    "script": [
      "cp $GCP_SERVICE_KEY gcloud-service-key.json"
    ],
    "__startline__": 131,
    "__endline__": 144
  }
}
```

The thing I am struggling with is that on string or list values there's no additional info on the start line and end line.
Is there a way to add that metadata to these objects too? Even if it means essentially converting them to dicts.

For example I'd like that instead of:

```json
"services": [
      "docker:find"
    ]
```

I'll get:

```json
"services": {
  1: [
      "docker:find"
    ]
  __start_line__ : ...
  __end_line__: ...
}
```

Comment: "The thing I am struggling with is that on **string** or list values there's no additional info on the start line and end line." Can you give an example output for string values? Does it apply to every string value within a list or a dict, even if the list or the dict itself has already included line information in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override [`construct_sequence`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) also to handle lists.

Here's an example:

```py
class SafeLineLoader(SafeLoader):
    # def construct_mapping...

    def construct_sequence(self, node: SequenceNode, deep: bool = False) -> dict[Hashable, Any]:
        mapping = super().construct_sequence(node, deep=deep)
        new_mapping = {
            '__values__': mapping.copy(),
            '__startline__': node.start_mark.line,
            '__endline__': node.end_mark.line
        }
        mapping.clear()
        mapping.append(new_mapping)
        return mapping
```

For this minimal YAML:

```yaml
.deploy_container:
  services:
  - docker:service1
  - docker:service2
```

Here's its JSON output:

```json
{
  ".deploy_container": {
    "services": [
      {
        "__values__": [
          "docker:service1",
          "docker:service2"
        ],
        "__startline__": 6,
        "__endline__": 12
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can adjust the mapping according to your requirements.